# AJAX POST 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, nginx, infinite-loop

I just finished creating infinite loop for my wordpress blog, It's working great on my local PC( WAMP), but when I put it online (nginx server) its showing `POST http://www.siteurl.com/infinite-loop.php 500 Internal Server Error`

**Infinite_loop.php**

```
<?php

$infinite_loop= $_POST['pcount']; ?>

<?php require_once("/wp-blog-header.php"); ?>

  <div class="x-container-fluid max width main">
    <div class="offset cf">
      <div class="<?php x_main_content_class(); ?>" role="main">
            <?php
                    global $wpdb;
                    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order' => 'DESC', 'offset'=>$infinite_loop );    
                    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


                        <div>
                            <div style="width:300px; float:left;"> 
                                <?php x_ethos_featured_index(); ?> 
                            </div>
                            <div style="width:500px; float:right;">
                                <?php /* print $args['offset']; */ ?>
                                <?php x_get_view( 'ethos', '_content', 'post-header' ); ?>
                                <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_content' ); ?>
                                <?php


                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </article>
                    <?php endforeach; 
                                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


</div>      <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div></div>
```

**AJAX IN THEME HEADER**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var post_page_count = 10;
var height_scroll = 400;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())){
        post_page_count = post_page_count+10;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: "theme/infinite_loop.php",
            data: {pcount:post_page_count},
            success:
                function(result){


                    $("#gizinfi").append(result);
                    }
        });
        };
});
});
</script>
```

I don't know whats the problem is. It's working great on local PC with WAMP but at online server its showing error. Can anyone please please help me to know what's the problem is? Please help...

Comment: Check what error you get by setting
    
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution...
it's a wordpress issue
Wordpress header is set to allow plugin style development externally. 
The header I included is incorrect, That's why I am getting 404 and 500 error.

I change that

```
<?php require_once("/wp-blog-header.php"); ?>
```

To

```
require('/wp-config.php');
 $wp->init();
 $wp->parse_request();
 $wp->query_posts();
 $wp->register_globals();
```

Answer (score 0):

For best WordPress practices you should use the [ajax functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) of WordPress. Put this in your theme functions.php file

```
<?php

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_inifinte_loop', 'my_inifinte_loop' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_inifinte_loop', 'my_inifinte_loop' );

    function my_inifinte_loop() {

        $infinite_loop= $_POST['pcount']; 

        ?>

          <div class="x-container-fluid max width main">
            <div class="offset cf">
              <div class="<?php x_main_content_class(); ?>" role="main">
                    <?php
                            global $wpdb;
                            $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'order' => 'DESC', 'offset'=>$infinite_loop );    
                            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                            foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>


                                <div>
                                    <div style="width:300px; float:left;"> 
                                        <?php x_ethos_featured_index(); ?> 
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="width:500px; float:right;">
                                        <?php /* print $args['offset']; */ ?>
                                        <?php x_get_view( 'ethos', '_content', 'post-header' ); ?>
                                        <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_content' ); ?>
                                        <?php


                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                            </article>
                            <?php endforeach; 
                                        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


              </div>      <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php


        die();

    }

?>
```

Than update your javascript to

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var post_page_count = 10;
var height_scroll = 400;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())){
            post_page_count = post_page_count+10;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>",
                data: {
                    pcount:post_page_count,
                    action: 'my_inifinte_loop'
                },
                success:
                    function(result){
                        $("#gizinfi").append(result);
                    }
            });
        };
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: 500 internal server error is gone, but that loop is not showing any post or title or image...

Comment: I've updated the code. Can you perform a console.log on the result?